# dynamically retrieving image in react?

Tags: reactjs, image, dynamic

I've been having some problems with figuring out how to import an image dynamically in react. After some research, I learned that the require() function is needed, so this is what I have tried so far:

`` <img src={require(`../../assets/${companyName}.png`)}></img> ``

But my web page is still producing a blank image. Is there any guidance or tips I can receive on this? I am using the create-react-app build for reference. Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're importing your image as:

```html
import companyName from '../../assets/companyName.png'
```

Try to add it like this:

```html
<img src={companyName} alt=''/>
```

Comment: i want to retrieve an image using a dynamic image path. the image is already uploaded locally and want to retrieve it dynamically

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54311204/how-to-do-dynamic-images-in-reactjs